# Why microsoft made JavaScriptSerializer obsolete prior to .net 3.5 SP1 and again active after that?

Tags: .net, asp.net, json

JavaScriptSerializer is not obsolete after .net 3.5 SP1. Should I uses JavaScriptSerializer or the prior recommended DataContractJsonSerializer?. Also why it was made obsolete?

Comment: Just to add more - JavaScriptSerializer and DataContractJsonSerializer aren't always compatible with each-other (DateTime, IIRC, is a pain).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'd happily use `JavaScriptSerializer` - but if in doubt, consider a third option - [Json.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx). Because it is 3rd party, it is unrelated to the MS decisions... that is a double-edged sword, of course - but it is often easier to get a minor fix applied to a standalone 3rd-party libary.

Comment: sorry i had to put this up here in comments but,using `.net 2.0 asmx service` which way should i go `DataContractJsonSerializer`,'JavaScriptSerializer' or `http://jayrock.berlios.de` i don't know if JSON.net is 2.0 compatible. We are just building a widget system and are relaying widgets as JSON data from webmethods.

Comment: @Deeptechtons well, JavaScriptSerializer isn't an option on 2.0, and neither is DataContractJsonSerializer. Frankly, DataContractJsonSerializer tends to produce atypical json. I would either: upgrade to 3.5/4.0 and use JavaScriptSerializer, or see if JSON.net etc are 2.0 friendly

Comment: thank you & btw is JSON - RPc any different from webmethods returning object?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9291423/json-rpc-libraries-for-use-with-net

Answer (score 6):

I have not seen definitive explanation. There were quite a few people upset when JavaScriptSerializer  was made obsolete.

Scott Gu made [this comment](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/10/01/tip-trick-building-a-tojson-extension-method-using-net-3-5.aspx) on his blog saying that he thought marking it as obsolete didn't make sense.

> The JavaScriptSerializer is currently marked obsolete - although I'm not sure why (was going to ask someone about this today).  It is very handy.  Note that obsolete doesn't mean removal in .NET 3.5 - it will be supported at least another version or two (or longer if I can convince them ).

I guess maybe he did convince them :-)

I have continued to use JavaScriptSerializer as its much more straight forward than the DataContractJsonSerializer.

Comment: Since the MVC team uses JavaScriptSerializer so heavily, it's unlikely it will be dropped in the future since MVC has caught such fire.

Comment: Of course [webAPI uses Json.Net](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/henrikn/2012/02/17/using-json-net-with-asp-net-web-api/) as standard. So microsoft are no longer chained to using either of these technologies. I believe there is talk of combining web api technologies with MVC so how long this dependency continues to be maintained is now questionable. IMO Json.Net wins every time.