# Difference between JSON Serialization

Tags: c#, json

What are the pros and cons of using the following two JSON serialization methods:

1. `System.Web.Script.Serialization`
2. `DataContractJsonSerializer`

Comment: possible duplicate of [System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer or System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.DataContractJsonSerializer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/831697/system-web-script-serialization-javascriptserializer-or-system-runtime-serializat)

Comment: That title reminds me of an old joke, "What's the difference between a duck?"

Comment: It doesn't quack when it's dead?

Answer (score 1):

**DataContractJsonSerializer**

> The primary purpose of the DataContractJsonSerializer is to be used with WCF, since one serialization is a big focus of WCF. Also, it is also better equipped to handle complex classes which have only certain properties available for serialization. This class is more strongly typed, has more knowledge about the type(s) it's handling and better error handling for badly-formed JSON.

.

**JavaScriptSerializer**

> This class on the other hand is much better equipped for quick serialization, it's a more cowboy approach. There's less error checking and less control over what properties which are serialized.

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/831697/system-web-script-serialization-javascriptserializer-or-system-runtime-serializat)