# Using JSON in .Net

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

What libraries are available to handle JSON in .Net? I've seen this: http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx but would prefer a native library, if possible.

Comment: What do you mean by "native" library? Method names written in some local language instead of English?

Comment: @Mehrdad:  He means one written entirely on the .NET framework, that does not rely on API calls.

Comment: If that's what "native" means, what's wrong with JSON.NET?

Comment: Nothing. I use JSON.NET myself. I think the OP is confused.  Maybe he means built-in-to-.NET

Answer (score 2):

I have been using the [`JavaScriptSerializer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx) some to expose data structures from a WCF service to Ajax calls, and it has been working out quite well.

Answer (score 1):

The [`JavaScriptSerializer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx) <strike>has been marked as obsolete in .NET 3.5 and</strike> but you could use the [`DataContractJsonSerializer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer.aspx).

EDIT: See [this question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/536359/why-microsoft-made-javascriptserializer-obsolete-prior-to-net-3-5-sp1-and-again) about whether `JavaScriptSerializer` is actually obsolete going forward in the .NET BCL. It looks like `JavaScriptSerializer` is no longer obsolete in .NET 3.5 SP1 - so it's probably fine to use that. If in doubt, you can use the contract serializer from WCF, or JSON.NET (if you're willing to include 3rd party code).

Here's some wrapper code to make using `DataContractJsonSerializer` nicer.

```
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Json;

public class JSONHelper
{
    public static string Serialize<T>(T obj)
    {
        DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = 
              new DataContractJsonSerializer(obj.GetType());
        using( MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream() ) 
        {
            serializer.WriteObject(ms, obj);
            string retVal = Encoding.Default.GetString(ms.ToArray());
            return retVal;
        }
    }

    public static T Deserialize<T>(string json)
    {
        using( MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(json)) )
        {
            DataContractJsonSerializer serializer =
                  new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T));
            T obj = (T)serializer.ReadObject(ms);
            ms.Close();
            return obj;
        }
    }
}
```

The code above is courtesy of: http://pietschsoft.com/post/2008/02/NET-35-JSON-Serialization-using-the-DataContractJsonSerializer.aspx,

I have altered it from it's original form to use best practices for object disposal (the `using` pattern .NET supports).

Comment: -1 for not wrapping streams in `using` blocks, and for creating an instance you later overwrite in the deserialize.

Comment: Good catch, John.  Do you agree about using this class, though?

Comment: @John Saunders: A fair ping. I've corrected that - although I will say I am not the original author of that code. Although I did change it in my own adapted implementation. It was just easier to find the site than my code :)

Comment: @Steven: Yes, I agree on the class.

Comment: @John: Thanks.  @LBushkin: You could probably drop the `ms.Close();`, since it should be closed automatically as it leaves the using block.

Comment: You are referencing `obj` before you declare it in the `Deserialize` method

Answer (score 0):

If you can require .Net 3.5, use System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer