# JSON Rpc libraries for use with .NET

Tags: asp.net, .net, json, asmx, json-rpc

I am looking into [JSON RPC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON-RPC) libraries for .net that are free to use in commercial applications. Up until now i just seem to have found [JROCK](http://code.google.com/p/jayrock/).

1. What other libraries, architecture have i got similar to JRock for **.NET 2.0**
2. What is the difference between a `[WebMethod]` in `asmx` web-service returning a instance of a class and a JSON Rpc method as in the JRock website page. Do i have any usability benefits, performance benefits or any benefits of using one over the other

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSON-RPC.NET http://jsonrpc2.codeplex.com/ is under a BSD license so you can use it in your commercial application. It has a ASP.net handler, but ASP.NET is not required. I have examples that run the server from a console application. It can work with sockets or pipes, or any transport you would like to plug into it. So you are not forced to use HTTP, but its there if you want to.

You should find that json rpc is more compact then asmx. It should reduce bandwidth, and could perform better for you, but you would want to test that.

I'm a contributer on the project, and would be interested to know if it meets your needs.

Comment: Hi any JSON Rpc library suits my needs now, we are just doing analysis on which library we can get up and running quickly your library seems to very good we shall try on this and let you know quickly

Comment: Hi any JSON Rpc library suits my needs now, we are just doing analysis on which library we can get up and running quickly your library seems to very good we shall try on this and let you know quickly but seems the idea of creating static class in global.asax is something extra!!