# What is the object in Dictionary<string, object> when Deserializing Json using JavaScriptSerializer?

Tags: c#, .net, json

I know what JSON is, but I don't understand when you deserialize a simple json property/value pair in a string of a bunch of property/value pairs like this: `{"fileName":"SomeName, "FilePath":"SomePath"}` then what is the object and string representing in your dictionary after being deserialized?

All we have here is a key/value pair which to me would be one object, but what's the string in the dictionary, the key right?  But what kind of key and why then would I need a dictionary to deserialize this to?  Why not just List and object would just contain your key/value pair?  or maybe List which would be same as object, but you're using a custom type.

I just want to understand when deserialized to a dictionary, what string and object are in the dictionary after being deserialized..more so what the string is in Dictionary.

I don't think I even need a  here right?  because there's no root object, just key/value (property/value) pairs so wouldn't  be fine for each json property/value?

Comment: JSON, strictly speaking, does not define ordering for objects. `[1,2,3]` would be deserialized to a List, perhaps, but `{k:v}` is not a list. It is a Map.

Comment: so really that's ONE json object I have in that example json above...with a bunch of properties....

Comment: That is one way to look at it, yes.

Answer (score 2):

From JSON perspective, `{"fileName":"SomeName, "FilePath":"SomePath"}` represents a object with given properties and respective values. You must also note that, in java-script, every object is essentially a dictionary/map but as such there is no dictionary data type in JSON representation - JSON specs uses term `object` to refer to a collection of name/value pairs. Quoted from [specs](http://www.json.org/):

> JSON is built on two structures:
>
> A collection of name/value pairs. In various languages, this is realized as an object, record, struct, dictionary, hash table, keyed list, or associative array.
>
> An ordered list of values. In most languages, this is realized as an array,
>   vector, list, or sequence.

Coming to the de-serialization, deserialization in JS is anyway an object (and also a dictionary because that's how JS objects are). Coming to deserialization to C#, said JSON can be deserialized into different types that maps to the same JSON form. For example, the said JSON could be deserialized to a `Dictionary<string, string>` or a instance of class with string properties of names `fileName` and `FilePath` (or it could be `HashTable` or it could a structure/class that have multitude of properties but only corresponding two are marked for serialization).

So typically, how you use a particular deserializer would decide the type after deserialization - AFAIK, .NET provided serializers accepts type to deserialize and produces a instance of that type. For `Dictionary<string, string>` deserialization, JSON.NET is the answer - see [How can I deserialize JSON to a simple Dictionary<string,string> in ASP.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207731/how-can-i-deserialize-json-to-a-simple-dictionarystring-string-in-asp-net)

Comment: would rather just take advantage of the JavaScriptSerializer, not use a whole library just for something so simple as to get one object from json that simply has a bunch of properties..one level no nested trees or anything in it.  I a not a fan pf using a huge 3rd party framework like JSON.NET until something gets so complex that I HAVE to.  This has to be simple with the existing JavaScriptSerializer without having to resort to reference a whole library like JSON.NET for this example.

Comment: @user1286569, yes - I agree with u but I am also a bit vary about using `JavaScriptSerializer` as MS once tried to make it obsolete (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/536359/why-microsoft-made-javascriptserializer-obsolete-prior-to-net-3-5-sp1-and-again) The alternative data-contract based serializer needs a type to specified while conversion. Let's hope .NET 4.5 would simplify the matter with introduction of `System.Json` - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.json%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

`{"fileName":"SomeName, "FilePath":"SomePath"}` is one object with 3 properties. Since objects in JavaScript are essentially dictionaries of properties the most obvious way to represent them in other languages is corresponding Dictionary/HashTable.

In .Net it is `Dictionary<string, object>` since name of propertye is always string, but value can have any type supported by JSON serialization(string, bool, array, object or number).

So result of `new JavaScriptSerializer().DeserializeObject("{\"fileName\":\"SomeName\", \"FilePath\":\"SomePath\"}")` is an object of type `Dictionary<string, object>` that contains list of all 2 properties of your object: string key "fileName" with corresponding value "SomeName" (type string, stored as object in the dictionary) and "FilePath" with value "SomePath".

Comment: ok so I'd only have one entry in my dictionary.  The one object here but then what would the string key contain? nothing? empty string?

Comment: See my edit on result of the call (also you probablyshould get LINQPad and try yourself too...)